# How do you drag-and-drop from a TableView's icon to a stationary icon?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How do we go about coding **drag-and-drop** (or tap-and-drag) from a cell in a TableView on an iPhone? I'd like to have a set of **drop** destination icons that are stationary. I've been trying touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchedEnded methods. These events fire nicely from a View so I can get a swipe to work nicely. Most likely the destination icons will be in a View so I think we are trying to get the **drag-and-drop** to begin in a TableView cell and end on an icon on a View that is beside the TableView.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to drag the entire `UITableViewCell`, or a `UIView` inside the cell? Either way, I don't think you'll be able to move the view outside the bounds of its parent, which would be the `UITableView`.

I have another project where I have a icon or tile (`UIImageView`) that the user can drag around the screen. After it reaches a certain distance, it snaps back.

Similarly, a possible solution might involve popping up a `UIView` (perhaps a `UIImageView`) over top of the table cell when the cell is tapped. The user could drag that around the screen, and you could make it disappear when it's "dropped" on whatever target you have.